# How to stop the background of text from extending all the way left and right when aligning to the center

Tags: css

I'm very very new to HTML and I'm trying to recreate a wix template for practice and i tried to align a piece of text to the center and I added a back background to it and the background expands all the way left and right. Is there a way to stop this?

```css
body {
  background-image: url(../images/Mountain-Landscapes-14.jpg);
}

h3.top {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Calibri', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Calibri', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 164px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h3.bottom {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 150;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 3.5px;
}

p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <h3 class="top" align='center'>AMBITION IS THE FIRST STEP TOWARDS</h3>
  <h1>SUCCESS</h1>
  <h3 class="bottom">Now Avaliable for Online Coaching</h3>
  <p>Book Now</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand if you want text to be align on center or just stop it expands all the way left and right

but something like this .... also here's codepen demo for better viewing [codepen](https://codepen.io/emmamar22241648/pen/xxPOEoY)

```css
body{
    background-image: url(../images/Mountain-Landscapes-14.jpg);
}
h3.top{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Calibri', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding-top: 35px;

}
h1{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Calibri', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    letter-spacing: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 164px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
h3.bottom{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 150;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 3.5px;
}
p{
color: white;
    background: black;
  
  margin: auto 0 auto 0; 
  /* top,right,bottom,left */
  width: 8%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="top">
     <h3 class="top" align='center'>AMBITION IS THE FIRST STEP TOWARDS</h3>
     <h1>SUCCESS</h1>
     <h3 class="bottom">Now Avaliable for Online Coaching</h3>
     <p>Book Now</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: now im getting confused- my problem is the background of the text "Book Now" is getting extended all the way to the left or right.

Comment: i updated the codepen the "Book Now" is now on center and the black border don't expand from left to rigth and i also added a background that make the text readable [click here to see codepen](https://codepen.io/emmamar22241648/pen/xxPOEoY)

Comment: this is whats happening to me - https://ibb.co/rpVhBP7

Comment: that's strange https://ibb.co/QCxBKNf

Comment: now im having even more problems with background, ive abandoned that project and started a new one and im trying to make a background for some text on the top and the background isnt extending to the edge of the page, no matter what i try

Answer (score 0):

Can't really tell the dimension of the image you used here, but you can set it using `background-size`, set it to `100% 100%` to fit the image's dimension to the container you're using. Then add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to prevent the image from repeating. See the snippet below for your reference.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/12/08/33/abstract-3147697_960_720.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

h3.top {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Calibri', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Calibri', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 164px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h3.bottom {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 150;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 3.5px;
}

p {
  color: white;
  enter code here text-align: center;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <h3 class="top" align='center'>AMBITION IS THE FIRST STEP TOWARDS</h3>
    <h1>SUCCESS</h1>
    <h3 class="bottom">Now Avaliable for Online Coaching</h3>
    <p>Book Now</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

More on `background-image` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp).

Comment: i just did background-image; url(thepicture.png); and it filled the whole screen. i dont know if its that i got lucky with the original size or if its because im using live server on vsc